# is there any way to parse a date in jq which contains milliseconds, or is there a way to get the interval between two dates without parsing?

Tags: jq

So basically i need to get an interval between 2 dates and i have found how to do that using mktime, then deducting the two numbers.

But from my searching in the strptime c library, there doesnt seem to be a way to parse a date containing milliseconds, so im asking if there is any way around this, or if there is any way to parse a date containing milliseconds.

Edit: if there is any way to round up or down the date, or just remove the milliseconds that would work too

example:

```
{
 "ActiveFrom": "2022-02-13T11:32:01.321345+04:00",
 "ActiveTo": "2022-02-13T11:33:13.031743+04:00"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip the fractional seconds with a substitution, and then go via `strptime` ([required because of non-UTC timezone](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1053)) to get a Unix timestamp:

```bash
echo '{
 "ActiveFrom": "2022-02-13T11:32:01.321345+04:00",
 "ActiveTo": "2022-02-13T11:33:13.031743+04:00"
}' \
  | jq '.ActiveFrom
      | sub("\\.[[:digit:]]+"; "")
      | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
      | mktime'
```

resulting in `1644751921` ([jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/YwMOC_mMNE0)).

Comment: Is this considering timezones? Altering it (e.g. to `-03:00`) seems to yield the same time. For instance, the output of `["2022-02-13T11:32:01.321345-03:00", "2022-02-13T11:32:01.321345+04:00"] | map(sub("\\.[[:digit:]]+"; "") | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")) | first == last` is `true` at [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/tvCx5RerPfz).

Comment: @pmf Hmm, indeed, it's not taking it into account; there's a [comment later on that issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1053#issuecomment-191287612) with a workaround tested on macOS, involving dropping the `:` and setting the `TZ` explicitly in the environment... I'll take another look in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are of OBJECT data type, you can easily calculate the interval like this:

```
var interval = date_later - date_early;
```